# Generate PDF file, each object in a new page using Yii framework 2 with mPdf

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf

Using Yii framework 2 with mPDF I tried to generate PDF file with multiple pages. I retrieved data with `ActiveRecord::find()->all();` which means I got many model objects back. I wanted to generate one PDF file with multiple objects, one page one object details. Below is the code in my action method:

```
// on top of the class signature
use mPDF;
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L');
    $mpdf->SetDefaultFont('SJIS');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
```

`$html` variable contents all the HTML tags. How can I configure it so that it creates new page for each object?

Answer (score 1):

you can insert `<pagebreak />` tag after each object.
it will insert a pagebreak. 
for more information check it

http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=108